# Aborting script when git operation is performed in midnight commander make input characters invisible

Tags: git, bash, mc

I have a script that performs git operations like checkout, fetch, pull and mvn clean  install in several repos. 
If I press CTRL-C when script executes git operations it stops. But after that I can't see characters I'm typing in that terminal. 
If I press enter I see that terminal executes typed command and see output but can't see characters I put into the terminal.
It is reproduced all the time in MC, but everything is OK in plain termminal.
Does anybody know what is the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: Does it matter where in the `git` operations you ctrl-c out?

Comment: Would `stty sane` after the break help you?

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thank you! Can you put it as the answer and explain a bit what is the reason of such behavior and why `stty sane` fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user3159253 for solution!
Executing `stty sane` in such terminal fix the situation.

It would be helpful if someone explains why input characters are invisible in terminal in such situation.